# possible to parameterise junit tests and run with maven?

Tags: maven, junit, automation, parameter-passing, selenium-webdriver

I have a bunch of selenium webdriver tests split in different classes. I run these tests across a number of sites but I don't want to run them all on every site.

In the past I used msBuild and c# and wrote testng tests for software automation and I could add something like @Version1.5 after @Test then when I run my tests if the version in my properties file wasn't 5.1 it would skip that test.

Is something like this possible using maven and junit in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Would JUnit Categories to the trick? Maven Surefire supports them but I am not sure how you would dynamically turn them on or off. You could definitely set up maven profiles to turn them on or off and then pass the appropriate profile as part of the maven command.